# MKMapView.annotations array is empty after creating annotations

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI project with a wrapped UIKit MapKit component for displaying annotations on a map. These annotations generate and call their respective delegate methods just fine (for example, the didSelect event). However, I need to update these markers on a `updateUIView` method that gets called when a binding is updated.

The issue I have is that the `updateUIView` gets called correctly when the binding gets updated, however I cannot access the `MKMapView` instances' `annotations` array, it is empty after I have created the annotations.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    self.UpdateUIMarker()
}

func UpdateUIMarker() {
    print(self.map.annotations.count)
}
```

On initial load of the map, the console does correctly print that there are 4 annotations associated with the `MKMapView` instance, however on subsequent method calls the console prints out a count of 0.

This is the binding

```
@Binding var ui_markers: [UIMarker]
```

And the respective `MKAnnotation` class I have defined

```
class UIMarker: NSObject, MKAnnotation, ObservableObject {
    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    public var nr: Int
    @Published public var complete: Bool

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, nr: Int, complete: Bool) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.nr = nr
        self.complete = complete
    
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Additionally, this is the delegate method for annotations in the `Coordinator`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard let ui_marker = annotation as? UIMarker else { return nil }
        
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "POI")
        
        if view == nil {
            view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: ui_marker, reuseIdentifier: "POI")
        }
        
        view?.image = UIImage(named: ui_marker.complete ? "map-marker-visited" : "map-marker")
        view?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        
        return view
}
```

The goal is as follows: an annotation is updated in the `ui_markers` binding array (the state of the property `completed` in a `UIMarker` is changed), the `updateUIView` picks up this change and changes the image of the respective `MKAnnotation`. So far, the `updateUIView` gets called correctly when the binding is updated and I can see which annotations have been completed in the `ui_markers` array, the problem is in accessing that annotation in the `MKMapView.annotations` array as the entire array seemingly gets emptied shortly after creation.

Let me know if additional info is required, and apologies in advance if I have missed something obvious, I am still very inexperienced with UIViewRepresentable and UIKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the issue was that inside the updateUIView method, I was working with the MKMapView instance that I had assigned to the class itself. Instead, all I needed to do was work with the MKMapView instance that was passed into the updateUIView method like this:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiViewController: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    self.UpdateUIMarker(map: uiViewController)
}
    
func UpdateUIMarker(map: MKMapView) {
    ///Instead of self.map.annotations, use map.annotations
    print(map.annotations.count)
}
```